# Is there a free implementation of printf for .net?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, printf

The problems:

- I can't use string.Format, I have C style format strings;
- I can't call the native printf (no P/Invoke);
- I can't use http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/PrintfImplementationinCS.aspx because of the license, I need something GPL-compatible.

Is there a free implementation of printf/sprintf for the .net framework? Other than the above link, I couldn't find anything.

Thanks!

**Update:**

Thanks for the help, even though you couldn't find anything. That means I'll just have to do it myself (I was trying to avoid it, but oh well...)

I cooked up a sprintf function that supports basic format strings, you can find it here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/printfnet/. I'll try to make it a complete implementation if I can.

Comment: I dont know why this has so many upvotes. An implementation using Regex can be done probably in 30-50 lines of trivial code...

Comment: I'm really curious why you absolutely NEED printf...

Comment: Why cant you use the CPOL license?  I cant see how that interfere's with your GPL requirement.

Comment: About the license issues, see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698610/is-the-code-project-open-license-a-gpl-compatible-license
And yes, I could implement it myself, but with all the flags, width/precision specifiers etc. it'd take time, lots of testing, and a bit more code than a few regexes.

Comment: The GPL is only incompatible if you are using someone elses GPL code.  If the project is your own, and it's GPL based, you can add an exception for any code you include yourself.  Having said that, maybe contacting the author and asking if he will give you a copy of the code under the GPL?

Comment: Mystere Man: Sometimes the most obvious solution occurs to me last... :) This time it didn't work though. I emailed him, but he didn't even answer.

Answer (score 4):

**I think you want this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/PrintfImplementationinCS.aspx**

It's a free implementation of a port of the C `printf` function to C#. You should be aware the author points out that not all features of `printf` are currently supported - but this may be a good starting point.

EDIT: *I see that the license for that version isn't compatible with what you need - in that case, I definitely recommend looking at calling the unmanaged version directly as the following blog article discusses. It's probably the most compatible and safest thing to do.*

**If that doesn't cut it, here's a blog article about actually calling the unmanaged `printf` function:**

http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/09/28/4473.aspx

It looks like this is all you need to call the unmanaged `printf` from C#:

```
[DllImport("msvcrt40.dll")]
public static extern int printf(string format, __arglist);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   printf("Hello %s!\n", __arglist("Bart"));
}
```

Comment: Be aware, typing __arglist into VS2008/2010 can crash the IDE. MS wont fix till next major version...

Comment: Thanks, but I target Silverlight too, so I can't call native functions.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you find a GPL-compatible implementation of `printf` written in C and port it to .NET?

Comment: If LGPL is good enough, the source code of the glibc is here: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/ - stdio-common contains the printf.c which calls the vprintf function in vfprintf.c. Pretty hairy code though...

Comment: Absolutely, not to rule out this idea in total, but the couple of implementations I have seen back in the days were more than unsuitable to be ported to C# - well at least if you care for code ;-) It might as well be easier to find an existing test suite and somehow program against that from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

How about a managed C++ wrapper?  Pretty sure you can call printf from there.

Comment: I target Silverlight too, so I can't call native functions.