# printf format in .NET

Tags: c#, printf

I have a `string format` and `IEnumerable< object > parameters` (collection of boxed values) in my managed C# code.

`format` - printf-like format specifier (according with ANSI/ISO 9899-1990),
`parameters` - collection of parameters (arguments) which need to process with the `format`.

The task - how to get final formatted string from format specifier and collection of arguments? (except http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/PrintfImplementationinCS.aspx solution)

Please do not answer "Why you need printf format? Use `String.Format`" or something like that... Unfortunately, I can not to escape from what I have...

Comment: Does the answer here help you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2359129/456813

Comment: @Phill: I think he's saying that he doesn't want to use that CodeProject solution.

Comment: I think Phill is referring to calling the unmananged printf.

Comment: @BoltClock - As Vlad states, I'm referring to the second half of the question which uses the unmanaged printf because the CodeProject solution doesn't support all printf functionality.

Comment: It would be greate if this possible (to use unmanaged printf or managed C++ wrapper) in this case. But my attempts was not succeed. I can not to find a way to convert IEnumerable< object > to va_list or __arglist.

Answer (score 1):

You have all the code for sprintf in [code project article "A printf implementtion in C#" from Richard Prinz](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19274/A-printf-implementation-in-C), modify it and compile it for your needs...
Mainly the first few lines... 
Add that project to your own project or just the only one c# file.

Comment: Hello Chase, I have not designed anything. I'm not the author. The code came from code project as said at the start of my answer. I probably should not have included any code. I remove it. I just added a direct link to it. Tha article is "A printf implementation in C#" from Richard Prinz.